# list numer of posts per category

Tags: php

Trying to get a code to display the categories of my posts and Im having an issue with presenting the number of posts per category.

well, you get my point while looking in the code, now the total number of categories is listed on every category...

here we go:

```
<?php 
$listresult = mysql_query("SELECT distinct category FROM test_blog") 
or die(mysql_error());

$totalpostspercategory = mysql_num_rows($listresult); 

echo "<ul>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $listresult )) {

if (strlen($row['category']) > 45) {
    $row['category'] = substr($row['category'],0,45) . " ...";
} 

echo "<li><a href='index.php?category=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['category'] ."</a> (" . $totalpostspercategory . ")</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: What are the results to your page?  is there an error, is the number wrong?  what is up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table looks something like this . . .

```
create table your_table (
  blog_post_id integer not null,
  category varchar(35) not null,
  primary key (blog_post_id, category)
);

insert into your_table values (1, 'food');
insert into your_table values (1, 'recipes');
insert into your_table values (1, 'tofu');
insert into your_table values (2, 'food');
insert into your_table values (3, 'tofu');
insert into your_table values (3, 'vacation');
```

You can get the count directly using SQL by

```
select category, count(*) num_posts
from your_table
group by category
order by category;

category  count
--
food      2
recipes   1
tofu      2
vacation  1
```

Comment: thx, thats exactly what I was looking for. how can I retrieve the info? i list $row['category'] but how do I echo the count?

Comment: Give the column an alias ("num_posts" above), and you should be able to access it with `$row['num_posts']`. The dbms will provide a column name if you don't provide an alias, but it's probably safer to do it yourself.  That way it won't change. (The name the dbms provides might change if you switch from, say, SQLite to MySQL. I'm not sure.)